# Problem in a python code for merge and sum of two data files

Tags: python

I have two codes in python which one of them is suppose to merge two files and the other one has to sum the rows of two files. But both of them produce the output file with one line while the input files consist of 8 lines.
This is the first code for merging two files of `output.txt` and `mass.txt`:

```py
outfile = open("output.txt", "r")
massfile = open("mass.txt", "r")
finaloutfile = open("final_output.txt", "w")
for line in outfile:
    finaloutfile.write(massfile.readline().rstrip("\n")+" "+line)

outfile.close()
massfile.close()
finaloutfile.close()
```

The second code is for adding the lines of two files `output.txt` and `earth.txt`:

```py
outfile = open("output.txt", "r")
earthfile = open("earth.txt", "r")
earthoutfile = open("earth_output.txt", "w")
for line in outfile:
    sl = line.split()
    lsl = len(sl)
    msl = earthfile.readline().split()
    idxmsl = 0

    for i in range(lsl-1):
        earthoutfile.write(str(float(sl[i])+float(msl[i]))+" ")
    earthoutfile.write(str(float(sl[lsl-1])+float(msl[lsl-1]))+"\n")

outfile.close()
earthfile.close()
earthoutfile.close()
```

What is the problem? Why they don't merge or add or lines of the input files?

Comment: What is it writing

Comment: i just tried your code and it works fine, please check again

Comment: @nassim Yes, it's strange that in my pc doesn't work!

Comment: I recommend you should avoid the simple file opening, use context manager instead (Eg.: `with open("output.txt", "r") as outfile`) because if you use the simple opening you are not able to be sure that the file will be closed correctly (nested file opening is also possible with contextmanager). Furthermore you should use the `%` formatting to write string into file and avoid the string concatenation with `+`. On the other hand it worked after merging for me. You should cross-check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the merging of two files I'd write something like this:

```py
outfile = open("output.txt", "r")
massfile = open("mass.txt", "r")
with open("final_output.txt", "a") as finaloutfile:
    outlines = outfile.readlines()
    masslines = massfile.readlines()
    for line in outlines:
        finaloutfile.write(line)
    for line in masslines:
        finaloutfile.write(line)

outfile.close()
massfile.close()
```

I just tested it and it works.

Comment: Now the out put is something like this : the first column which belongs to mass.txt but the other lines of output.txt are omitted again.

Comment: @ndee can you please show how mass.txt and output.txt are (simplifyed) and how you'd want the final_output.txt to be?

Comment: Thanks for asking it! I checked the files again. The problem was due to file `output.txt` which hasn't the same number of lines as file `mass.txt`.  Now it works fine!